# nasm add two arrays together slot by slot, into a third array

Tags: assembly, nasm

working on a 32bit architecture and i'm adding two arrays together slot by slot into a third array so if I have 3,4,4 and 4,4,4 in the arrays the third array should contain 7,8,8 at the end of the function

I was able to pass in the arrays correctly and the amount of items into the function arleady, i know this because I ran test code

now i'm working on the addition part of it, here is what I have, the logic makes sense to me but it's still seg faulting...ideas?

```
;*************************************ADD ARRAY**********************************************
segment .bss
;
segment .data
summessage  db  "The Sum is: ", 0
segment .text
extern readdouble,print_string, read_int, writedouble, print_nl, print_int
    global addarray
addarray:
    pusha
    mov edi, 0      ;initialize counter to 0
    mov ecx, 0      ;zero out ecx and edx
    mov edx, 0

    mov ebx, [esp+48]   ;moves starting location of array1 into ebx
    mov edi, [ebp+40]   ;move quantity into edi 
    mov ebp, [esp+60]   ;move the starting location of array2 into ebp

    mov esi, [esi]  ;move starting locatino of array3 into esi

    ;mov    ecx, [ebp]
    ;mov    edx, [ebp+4]
    ;call   writedouble
    ;call   print_nl

add_loop:

    fld     qword [ebx]      ;The second input is now in a floating point register, specifically st0.
    fld qword [ebp]

    fadd                 ;The first input is added to the second input and the sum
                         ;replaces the second input in st0

    fstp    qword [ecx] ;copy top of stack onto ecx
    mov ecx,[ecx]
    mov edx,[edx+4] 

    mov [esi], ecx
    mov [esi+4], ecx
    add esi, 8      ;increment to the next loaction of esi

    add ebx,8       ;increment location of ebx to the next floating point value of array1
    ;add    ebp,8       ;increment location of ebp to the next floating point value of array2

    dec edi     ;increment counter

    cmp edi, 0      ;compare to see if all values have been added
    jz  add_done
    jmp add_loop
add_done:
    popa
    ret
```

Comment: Do you have any idea where it's crashing? Can you single-step the code to see what's happening?

Comment: i already made sure that my array positions and items are correct, i did that  by writing test code...                                                next thing to do by single step? I'm not sure if i'm using the floating commands correct?

Answer (score 1):

The segfault is probably coming from `fstp qword [ecx]`. At the beginning of addarray, you set ecx to 0, and then you attempt to store a value at that address, which the system doesn't allow. As mentioned by Brendan, you can directly store the value to the output array:

```
; This replaces five lines starting with your current fstp instruction
fstp qword [esi]
```

Next, why did you comment the increment of ebp? With that commented, you will always add the first item of the second array to the current element of the first.

Finally, you can shorten the code which determines whether or not you need another loop by two instructions. `dec` automatically sets the zero flag if it results in 0, so you do not need the `cmp` instruction, and you can tell it to go to another loop if it is not zero, but just let it continue if it is:

```
dec edi ; decrement number of remaining elements
jnz add_loop
; If edi is zero, this will just continue into add_done
```

*Edited as Brendan suggested storing directly to the output array*

Comment: Could also store the result in the right place to begin with (e.g. "fstp    qword [esi]") rather than storing it in a temporary place and copying it.